# Python PIL ValueError : images do not match

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, valueerror

I'm using PIL and came across this problem. I don't know what is it that I'm doing wrong. Here is my code :

```
from PIL import Image

# Load the two images
bg = Image.open('Background.png')
baseman = Image.open('Baseman.png')

# Resize the second image to match the size of the first image
baseman = baseman.resize(bg.size)

# Create a new image with alpha channel
result = Image.new('RGBA', bg.size)

# Mix the two images using alpha compositing
result = Image.alpha_composite(result, bg)
result = Image.alpha_composite(result, baseman)

# Save the result image
result.save('result.png')
```

I expected that the output of the project be a mixture of 3 png files. But I faced this error :
ValueError: images do not match
I've reviewed the answer of similar problems and none of them solved it.

Comment: What line gives the error?

Answer (score 1):

`Image.resize` returns a copy of the Image. You are changing elements of the list, but `bg`, `baseman` and `bzamin` variables still point to the old, unresized images.
Either reassign them or change later references to `pics[0]`, `pics[1]` and `pics[2]`.